# Outlook 2010 conditional formatting for message preview body

Tags: outlook, ms-office

In outlook 2010 when you use conditional formatting I can only seem to change the message *subject* in the little preview pane thing. Is there a way to also, say, bold the preview of the message *body* along with the message subject instead of only bolding the message subject for unread emails?

Answer (score 2):

No, only the explorer message list uses custom formatting.